# Flutter using the map function to create a statless widget for each element in a list

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a list books which have Books objects like

```
List<Books> books = [
 Books(
  bookname: 'The Disasters',
  author: 'M.K England',
  favicon: Icons.star,
  rate: 3.9,
  bookcategory: 'Fiction',
  booksimage: 'images/a7a.jpg',
 ),
];
```

How can I iterate through each item in the list and create separate statless widget for each one so when a new Books object is added to the list a statless widget will created automatically like this

```
class books extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Text('the book name')
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListView.builder to iterate through all the items in the list.

```
List<Books> booksList = [
Books(
  bookname: 'The Disasters',
  author: 'M.K England',
  favicon: Icons.star,
  rate: 3.9,
  bookcategory: 'Fiction',
  booksimage: 'images/a7a.jpg',
),
];

class books extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: booksList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text("${booksList[index].bookname}");
      },
    );
  }
}
```